# Как вывести сердечко в консоли используя цикл for?

Tags: java, консоль, for, символы, рисование

Нужно вывести вот так

[image: вот так надо]

Получается вот так

[image: вот так получается]

Мой код

```
public class loveYevhen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("love you");
        for (int i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j > i; j--) {
                System.out.printf(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.printf("<3");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 4; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.printf(" ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.printf("<3");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Если по каким-то причинам очевидное решение "в лоб" (вывести непосредственно каждую строку изображения при помощи `println()`, не используя циклы, выводящие изображение по одному "пикселю") не подходит, я бы посоветовал не хардкодить форму сердечка в циклах (это очень сложно читать и отлаживать), а использовать простенькое [RLE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)-кодирование. Смысл вот в чём: у вас, по сути, чёрно-белое изображение, в котором чёрным мы будем считать пробелы, а белым - символы `<3` (или наоборот, это не важно). Кодировать будем длины серий из подряд повторяющихся "пикселей": `2 ' ', 1 '<3', 2 ' ', 1 '<3', 2 ' '`. Интерпретировав такую последовательность мы получим первую строку вашего изображения: `'  <3  <3  '`. Так можно поступить с каждой строкой, но мы пойдём немного дальше.

Во-первых, у вас каждая строка изображения имеет фиксированную длину - 10 символов. Значит, можно не разбивать закодированное изображение на строки, а кодировать всю последовательность подряд. То есть, вместо отдельных последовательностей для каждой строки мы кодируем строку, которая получилась бы после "склеивания" всех строк изображения в одну. Изображение

```
  <3  <3  
 <3<3<3<3 
<3<3<3<3<3
 <3<3<3<3 
  <3<3<3  
   <3<3   
    <3
```

превращается в

```
  <3  <3   <3<3<3<3 <3<3<3<3<3 <3<3<3<3   <3<3<3     <3<3       >3    
^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^        ^
1         2         3         4         5         6         7       // границы строк
```

а эта последовательность, в свою очередь, превращается в

```
2 ' ', 1 '<3', 2 ' ', 1 '<3', 3 ' ', 4 '<3', 1 ' ', 5 '<3', 1 ' ', 4 '<3' ...
```

Декодировав эту строку и вставив переводы строки через каждые 10 символов, мы получим исходное изображение.

Во-вторых, нам даже не обязательно указывать, какие именно символы мы кодируем в каждой последовательности. Мы знаем, что после последовательности пробелов всегда будет последовательность `<3` и наоборот. Тогда мы можем просто кодировать длины последовательностей и начальный символ:

```
2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, ... (начинать с ' ')
```

Получив такую последовательность на вход, мы будем декодировать её, чередуя символы: `2 ' ', 1 '<3', 2 ' ', 1 '<3'`, и т. д. Полученную в результате строку разбиваем на подстроки по 10 символов и выводим на экран.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так.

```
System.out.println("love you");
System.out.println("  <3  <3");

for (int i = 4; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 5; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.printf(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.printf("<3");
    }

    System.out.println();
}

for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (int j = 4; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.printf(" ");
    }

    for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.printf("<3");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае не требуются отдельные части для печати верхней и нижней половинок, за счет итерации `i` от отрицательных до положительных чисел.

Например, для `n=4`, `i` проходит от `-3` до `+8`, оба включительно.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNc4IwEL3zK/YGKFJ1pvaAdtrppZeePLYeAoJEITBJ0HE6zvS39Kf1j9ANQcCPjs2BLJu3b19edk22ZJDlIVsvN2VJ0zzjEtaYdAtJE7fnGUaQECHgJeZUyJSI15BwKeDTAFx54Sc0ACGJxG2b0SXknDJZgSwMgDkQxISDn5BgU8e7mMrQrinUohFYDKYzGNpNTi0eyoIzr8Uh4Y4uZQwzuIceMBjAuD1W5O8L8IsIz1m404mqYNGiooxDJY0iaoQMzMNwCpZm7sPIhjukBdrvd0UeBWSFDDmWvhEZu8QXFrXxXiHT2bEiVLJQHvVOip85J3vhRjRJLNToaE/sG6Chozs6tW034PoSg6ZG/V4vVabXsh/Pjb9KbR25dVXlktPadpK91nC@FzJMXVTmVkOSMMXbAR0M/f3vaHVfp3OGI2d@FOPJ5N48RiOzbvM3eUoos@YSaVY4Q4SvRJe@GRqGbzz0oJrWCe6XM3Km5EmJ@Pn6Nm@7cWHFGd1Dc4lDWf4C)

```java
class ChristmasHearts {
  public static void printHeart(int n, char black, char white) {
    if (n <= 0)
      return;
    int width = 5 * n - 2;
    char[] buf = new char[width];
    for (int i = 1 - n; i < (width + 1) / 2; i++) {
      int outer = Math.abs(i), center = 2 - n - 2 * i;
      Arrays.fill(buf, black);
      Arrays.fill(buf, 0, outer, white);
      Arrays.fill(buf, width - outer, width, white);
      if (center > 0)
        Arrays.fill(buf, (width - center) / 2, (width + center) / 2, white);
      System.out.println(buf);
    }
  }

  public static void printHeart(int n) {
    printHeart(n, '\u2665', '\u2661');
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int n = 0; n <= 6; n++) {
      printHeart(n, '@', '•');
      System.out.println();
    }
    printHeart(7);
  }
}
```

Вывод:

```
@•@
•@•
```

```
•@@••@@•
@@@@@@@@
•@@@@@@•
••@@@@••
•••@@•••
```

```
••@@@•••@@@••
•@@@@@•@@@@@•
@@@@@@@@@@@@@
•@@@@@@@@@@@•
••@@@@@@@@@••
•••@@@@@@@•••
••••@@@@@••••
•••••@@@•••••
••••••@••••••
```

```
•••@@@@••••@@@@•••
••@@@@@@••@@@@@@••
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••
•••@@@@@@@@@@@@•••
••••@@@@@@@@@@••••
•••••@@@@@@@@•••••
••••••@@@@@@••••••
•••••••@@@@•••••••
••••••••@@••••••••
```

```
••••@@@@@•••••@@@@@••••
•••@@@@@@@•••@@@@@@@•••
••@@@@@@@@@•@@@@@@@@@••
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••
•••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•••
••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••••
•••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@•••••
••••••@@@@@@@@@@@••••••
•••••••@@@@@@@@@•••••••
••••••••@@@@@@@••••••••
•••••••••@@@@@•••••••••
••••••••••@@@••••••••••
•••••••••••@•••••••••••
```

```
•••••@@@@@@••••••@@@@@@•••••
••••@@@@@@@@••••@@@@@@@@••••
•••@@@@@@@@@@••@@@@@@@@@@•••
••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
•@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•
••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••
•••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•••
••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••••
•••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•••••
••••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@••••••
•••••••@@@@@@@@@@@@@@•••••••
••••••••@@@@@@@@@@@@••••••••
•••••••••@@@@@@@@@@•••••••••
••••••••••@@@@@@@@••••••••••
•••••••••••@@@@@@•••••••••••
••••••••••••@@@@••••••••••••
•••••••••••••@@•••••••••••••
```

```
♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡
♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡
♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡
♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡
♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡♡
```

---

<sup>См. [Draw a heart in ASCII-art style based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310765)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Много кода, и он почти работает!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVZNbxMxEL33Vwy9dEOaNAkHDmk4UCq1ElBEKnEADs5mNuvWsVdeb0NV5Ydw5MAf44@E8W4@7N1NSCRgLpac53lvxrPPuWMPrKUSlHfj@8UiFCxN4T0P8SJmQqCcIDwdAUWSjQQPITXM0BJxyQSEMdNwcfP25uPlGxjAya/vP0/6u9Gfrq5vLwvsD8LWgB8UH0OiuTS3KglogSxFfS2TzDSWWmwMDUEmr7MoQg1azSinxJm3HTSWBDZsohkfm5iAPXgOwTortKDbgCa8oN31pnPy7AxmMTcIMTJtUmAGTIygMpPyMXoEtIf6qoANwGPou/kERgZCJZTGMaQYGq4kKE1b00SgQRe7ggkuESKtpjk7lYKpgUQRrSehEDkscnZdFZ4CzSfxUoIroHMoQ28rg9ezEZoZoqTOl6pOvdRcyrr@OZcxUkogk5AlCeoPBCSc0RluqIlXIASlPryCjjs9NiKqN58vTjk6fVrO3QukjWazfMYGDVubEb0cB/k0N/oeZP5HEl/aPjzLb@xgJqef/6mc3r8s56/fjgM@/iKPS1gekUus5qyOywLcT75myFbhwFqtfi3EH/53zMTtKfsWdE69X1rQa2w5X1IzGGyXY6PiFLk99vfD9/JbqcXOAUWK@xM3yZD3Zt0Onh8dJMS6sHXUGacnQUnxuHamgvF026ncICU9OOSY1ieXDkcnsxBrD7leFTGSVC1gvmNI7b0@2zmHzq03m9XkpX63Ki2s8pWOnNtRquQdaWT3m0ybLMPH1OC0TbLa@UMuZGC/NKOK1zloLCd4vvX9nzIugwL9@SswPUnduj1v6ObeMICXhSV4Kjd/I9aM88XiNw)

```java
class NiceChallenge {
    public static final char COLORED = '♥';
    public static final char WHITE = '♡';

    public static void printTop(int userInput) {
        StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer();

        int width = 2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput;

        // white hearts at the outside
        int outerHearts = userInput - 1;
        // left colored section or complete
        // colored line from the widest point
        int heartsSection1 = userInput;
        // right color section or 0 from the widest point
        int heartsSection2 = userInput;
        // white hearts between 2 colored sections
        int innerHearts = userInput;

        boolean upperPart = true;
        while (heartsSection1 > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < outerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heartsSection1; i++) {
                row.append(COLORED);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < innerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heartsSection2; i++) {
                row.append(COLORED);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < outerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            row.append("\n");
            if (upperPart) {
                if (outerHearts > 0) {
                    outerHearts--;
                    innerHearts = Math.max(0, innerHearts - 2);
                    if (outerHearts == 0) {
                        heartsSection1 = width;
                        heartsSection2 = 0;
                    } else {
                        heartsSection1 += 2;
                        heartsSection2 += 2;
                    }
                } else {
                    // line with only colored hearts,
                    // from now on the hearts reduce
                    upperPart = false;
                }
            }
            if (!upperPart) {
                outerHearts++;
                heartsSection1 -= 2;
            }
            if (heartsSection1 <= 0)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(row.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTop(3);
    }
}
```

Вывод `n=3`:

```
♡♡♥♥♥♡♡♡♥♥♥♡♡
♡♥♥♥♥♥♡♥♥♥♥♥♡
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡
♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡
♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♥♥♥♡♡♡♡♡
♡♡♡♡♡♡♥♡♡♡♡♡♡
```

---

<sup>См. [Draw a heart in ASCII-art style based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63935154)</sup>